# Multiple threads in a webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I have a working web service which On load contacts different websites and scrapes relevant information from them. As the requirements grew so did the number of httpwebrequests.

Right now I'm not using any asynchronous requests in the web service - Which means that ASP.net renders one request at a time. This obviously became a burden as one request to the webservice itself can take up to 2 minutes to complete.

Is there a way to convert all these httpwebreqeusts inside the webservice to multi-threaded?

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with .Net V4+, you can use the Parallel library or task library which allow easily to do such things.

If you call all your web services using the same way (assuming all web services respects the same WSDL, just differing urls, you can use something like this) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string StartUrl = @"http://blog.hand-net.com";

        private static void Main()
        {
            var content = DownloadAsString(StartUrl);

            // The "AsParallel" here is the key
            var result = ExtractUrls(content).AsParallel().Select(
                link =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("... Fetching {0} started", link);
                    var req = WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(link));

                    var resp = req.GetResponse();

                    var info = new { Link = link, Size = resp.ContentLength};

                    resp.Close();

                    return info;
                }
                );

            foreach (var linkInfo in result)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Link : {0}", linkInfo.Link);
                Console.WriteLine("Size : {0}", linkInfo.Size);
            }
        }

        private static string DownloadAsString(string url)
        {
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                return wc.DownloadString(url);
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> ExtractUrls(string content)
        {
            var regEx = new Regex(@"<a\s+href=""(?<url>.*?)""");
            var matches = regEx.Matches(content);

            return matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["url"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

This small program first download an html page, then extract all href. This produces an array of remote files.
the AsParralel here allow to run the content of the select in a parallel way.

This code does not have error handling, cancellation feature but illustrate the AsParallel method.

If you can't call all your webservices in the same way, you can also use something like this :

```
        Task.WaitAll(
            Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>GetDataFromWebServiceA()),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>GetDataFromWebServiceB()),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>GetDataFromWebServiceC()),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>GetDataFromWebServiceD()),
            );
```

This code will add 4 tasks, that will be run "when possible". The WaitAll method will simply wait for all task to be completed before returning.

By when possible I mean when a slot in the thread pool is free. When using the Task library, there is by default one thread pool per processor core. If you have 100 tasks, the 100 taks will be processed by 4 worker threads on a 4 core computer.